# calling header from a subfolder

Tags: html, css

I am organizing my files in the rootfolder. The basic problem is that the CSS and JS is not called. From the "page-services-3.php" I have to call the header. Because the php site is laying in a subfolder, I have tried with the following:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/includes/header.php' ?>

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/includes/footer.php' ?>
```

I tried with a normal href to the CSS(like the picture below) and I also set this infront of my CSS files in the header:

```
<link href="http://localhost:8888/Portfolio-Version-2//plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

But I am just getting the following page:

[image]

How is the correct syntaxs to call a header from a subfolder? The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is working for me with the exact same folder structure in some other projects.

**UPDATE**

After the answer I tried to do the following:

In my page-services.php I tried the following:

```
<?php require"http://localhost:8888/'resources/includes/header.php'"; ?>

    <body class="no-trans    ">

<?php require"http://localhost:8888/'resources/includes/navbar.php'"; ?>

<?php require"http://localhost:8888/'resources/includes/banner.php'"; ?>
```

and i Tried to set the base in the header.php, index.php like this:

```
<?php define("http://localhost:8888/",dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))); ?>
```

This is just resulting in the following error:

*The localhost page isn’t working*

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path? Modify, say, your main stylesheet reference to /css/style.css and see if it loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this in the index page 
just define the website path

```
define("SITE_URL",dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])));
```

SITE_URL : contain the `'http://localhost:8888/'`
than u can call any file in the server 
php file u can do

```
require"SITE_URL.'some_folder/some_file.php'";
```

or css file u can do

```
<link href="<?echo  SITE_URL.'/some_folder/some_file.css';?> " rel="stylesheet">
```

for more explain how to mare php router visit  [php router](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/creation-d-un-espace-membre-php-mysql-partie-4-la-structure-php-du-site--221)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I have updated my question. If you have time I would really appreciate if you had a look

Comment: where is ur question